# How to view and disable auto crystal reports in business objects enterprise release 2?

Tags: crystal-reports, business-objects, infoview

I'm new to business objects and have been assigned a ticket to disable a certain auto crystal report that sends email to specific people with a pdf attachment. Now I need to find and totally disable that certain crystal report. Thank you in advance for the help.

Regards, 
Clef

Comment: Is that XIr2 or BI4.2?

Comment: Hi Joe, it's XIr2.

Comment: That's really old so I can't give you step by step instructions.  Are you able to log into CMC or Infoview?

Comment: Yes, I can able to login in infoview.

Answer (score 0):

In Infoview, click on Public Folders and then enter the report name in the search box.  This should bring up the report.  From here, right click on the report, and hit "History".  In the history list you *should* find one (or more) in "Recurring" status.  Delete or disable the recurring instances, and that will prevent the report from running.  You can click on the status ("Recurring" in this case) to see the details of the schedule, including the destination.

If you are unable to locate the report by name, you can get a list of all scheduled reports.  It's a different URL, though: http://server/businessobjects/enterprise115/adminlaunch

There is a link for "Instance Manager". This should help you identify the report, and you can then locate it in Infoview.

Comment: Hi Joe, thank you very much for your help, I do exactly as you say but didn't find the report. I think it is not present in our system. I think the link you provided is unreachable. 